# Why do I not get the correct result when multiplying extremely large numbers?

Tags: c#

I wrote this code but sometimes the same input doesn't give me the same output. For example, input 128 or 97.

My C# code is:

```
age = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double result1 = age *3.156e7;
int result2 = age * 31560000;
```

Comment: int max value is 2,147,483,647 and  128 * 31560000 = 4,039,680,000 which is greater than int max value,  and you will get an [Integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)

Comment: Thanks, but long also have this problem.

Comment: `age` is integer and `31560000` is also integer so the outcome of `age * 31560000` will be assigned to an integer and that overflows it and that's why you get some junk value in `result2`.  you need to change `int age` to `long age` and `int result2` to `long result2`. That would give you the same expected result for `result1` and `result2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int` max value is 2,147,483,647 and 128 * 31560000 = 4,039,680,000 which is greater than int max value, and you will get an Integer overflow

But also age * 31560000 output an `int` which his max value is also as above

It doesn't matter if you do

```
int = age * 31560000
```

or

`long = age * 31560000`

(here you expect to get the result as you think but you will get still get an overflow because the compiler first compute the multiple results and then insert it into the result)

to solve this you can do something like this

```
long result2 = age * Convert.ToInt64(31560000);
```

because the compiler looks here for higher format and act according to it

Comment: `31560000L` works as well. the `L` literal tells that its a long not int.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I know, i wanted to emphasize that the value should be converted to higher order